# How I can use LINQ in razor view?

Tags: linq, razor

Could you tell me how can I use LINQ in razor view. I've added System.Data.Linq reference to my MVC project and I'm still not able to write my own queries.

Comment: The controller is responsible for sending the correct data to the view. Do not use linq in a razor view

Comment: Acronym capitalization.

Comment: If using Razor as a templating engine then using LINQ is a valid use case.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `@using System.Data.Linq` at the top of your view, or add `<add namespace="System.Data.Linq" />` to the web.config in `<system.web.webPages.razor><pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"><namespaces>` section.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thank You for help. I really appreciate that.